# An example of a mobile REST to database architecture

Tags: database, rest, architecture

Does anyone have an architecture for a REST application optimized for mobile. The architecture I would like to see manages REST requests and responses in conjunction with a database.  Ideally I would like to see an architecture that has the ability to scale and is flexible to change.

Comment: This is a very general question. What do you mean by "optimized for mobile"? As for a RESTful design, I think ROA (Resource Oriented Architecture) is the way to go. Scalability and flexibility are basic assumptions of this style. What you can achieve depends on what components you actually need and how fine-grained your system is. So far, you've just said you want to use a database, mobile apps and representational state transfer. It's hard to be more vague than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience RESTlets and Hibernate are good solutions for implementing a REST to Database solution using ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at MVVM architectural pattern. There are tons of MVVM tutorials but you can start with [Silverlight client for REST using MVVM](http://hsuhanda.blogspot.com/2010/09/silverlight-client-for-rest-using-mvvm.html) post. Also see this question [Good architecture for consuming a REST web service in an MVVM app for Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182229/good-architecture-for-consuming-a-rest-web-service-in-an-mvvm-app-for-windows-ph)